# Flatten nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, nested, flatten

I have a json object like this:

```
const people = {
name: 'My Name',
cities: [{city: 'London', country: 'UK'},{city: 'Mumbai', country: 'IN'},{city: 'New York', country: 'US'}],
}
```

I would like the output like this: i.e for each cities, I would like to flatten array.

```
[
  ['My Name', 'London', 'UK'], 
  ['My Name','Mumbai', 'IN'],
  ['My Name','New York', 'US']
]
```

I have tried flatten etc and could not figure out how to achieve this.
Could someone please help me?
Thanks,
Sasi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want JSON output:

```js
const people = {
  name: 'My Name',
  cities: [{city: 'London', country: 'UK'},{city: 'Mumbai', country: 'IN'},{city: 'New York', country: 'US'}],
}

let result = people.cities.map(data => {
  return {
    name: people.name,
    city: data.city,
    country: data.country
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

### To scale this for multiple people:

```js
const peopleExtended = [{
  name: 'My Name',
  cities: [{
    city: 'London',
    country: 'UK'
  }, {
    city: 'Mumbai',
    country: 'IN'
  }, {
    city: 'New York',
    country: 'US'
  }],
}, {
  name: 'Person 2',
  cities: [{
    city: 'Birmingham',
    country: 'UK'
  }, {
    city: 'Delhi',
    country: 'IN'
  }, {
    city: 'New York',
    country: 'US'
  }],
}]

function flattenCities(person) {
  return person.cities.map(data => {
    return {
      name: person.name,
      city: data.city,
      country: data.country
    }
  })
}

peopleExtended.forEach(person => {
    let flatArray = flattenCities(person);
  console.log(person.name, flatArray)
})
```

Comment: This works perfect with JSON. To extend this, if I have a array of json, example:
const people =[ {
  name: 'My Name',
  cities: [{city: 'London', country: 'UK'},{city: 'Mumbai', country: 'IN'},{city: 'New York', country: 'US'}],
},{
  name: 'Person 2',
  cities: [{city: 'Birmingham', country: 'UK'},{city: 'Delhi', country: 'IN'},{city: 'New York', country: 'US'}],
}]
How this works?
Thanks

Comment: Sure! Simply put the flattening code into a function and then call that each time you loop through a person. See my edits.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick!

```js
const people = {
  name: 'My Name',
  cities: [{city: 'London', country: 'UK'},{city: 'Mumbai', country: 'IN'},{city: 'New York', country: 'US'}],
}

function flattenIt(obj) {
  const name = obj.name;
  const cityData = obj.cities;
  return cityData.map(({city, country}) => [name, city, country])
}

console.log(flattenIt(people));
```

Comment: You are a star! Excellent answer. I was struggling for few hours and you made my day in a jiffy.